# Flash app on android

Tags: android

I am new to android development. I have a tablet with android supporting flash and have successfully installed it on the device.

I have created a flash app and now would like to run it on my device. How do I do this?

I have used the Android sdk and eclipse.

Comment: means you have APK file of an app and you want to run it on your tablet?

Comment: Do you want to run your flash app in your device or emulator?

Comment: i have air file and want to run on my tablet not emulator

Comment: Whats your 'problem related with programming'..?

Comment: I don't if this is related with programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1:** Enable USB debugging on the device.
Make sure the device is not connected to the computer and then go to Settings > Applications > Development and select USB debugging on the device.

[image]

**Step 2:** Attach the device to the computer.
Connect the Google Android device to your computer's USB port.

On Windows you may also need to install a driver for the device; this may be supplied as part of the software package for your device or you can follow the steps outlined in the Flex documentation to install the Android USB device drivers.

**Step 3:** Run the application on the device.
To install and run the application on the device, you create a run configuration to run on a Google Android device.

In Flash Builder, select Run Configurations from the Run menu or from the dropdown list for the Run button and click the new or duplicate button to create a new run configuration.
Name the new configuration, set the target platform to Google Android, set the launch method to On device.

[image]

Click the Run button. Flash Builder packages the application as an APK file, transfers it to the device, installs the AIR runtime on the device (if not already installed), and launches the application.

[image]

Figure 3. Install and run the application on the device.
Look at the list of applications on the device. You will see your application listed using a default name and icon. You will learn to customize the name and icon in a later section.

[image]

Locate the Google Android package file, the APK file, in your project's bin-debug folder. This is a debug version of the application for development. You learn to create a release version of the APK for distribution in the next section.

[image: **enter image description here**]

**Step 4:** Debug the application on the device.
To debug an application on a device, you use Flash Builder to create and install a debug APK package just as you did for running the application on a device. For debugging, though, your computer and the device must be on the same Wi-Fi network. The USB cable is used to install the application on the device; the Wi-Fi network is used for all communication between the device and Flash Builder when the application is running and being debugged.

In Flash Builder, select your Google Android device configuration profile from the drop-down menu for the Debug button and click Debug.

If you get a dialog box asking for the IP address of the host computer, enter it.

Flash Builder installs and launches the application on the device as before, but now when a breakpoint in the code is reached, the application will freeze and you can use Flash Builder to step through code exactly as when using the device emulator

If you have trouble debugging on the device, check to see if you computer is on a VPN or using a firewall. If the computer is on a VPN and the device is not, you may need to take the computer off the VPN for debugging to work. If you have a firewall turned on, try disabling it. If you cannot or do not want to disable it, try opening port 7935, the port used by the Flash Builder debugger to communicate with the device.